# How do I import protractor for use in my Typescript project?

Tags: typescript, automation, gulp, protractor

I am trying to use protractor within my project to automate the use of a browser.

I have been unable to get Protractor recognized in my project, as when I run my code I get the following errors:

```
error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'protractor'.
```

Previously, I was able to reference protractor generated in my /typings directory during runtime.  However, when I run my project now, the file is no longer generated since I upgraded my version of protractor to the latest.

I have also tried the solution mentioned online:

```
import {browser} from 'protractor'
```

UPDATE: I do not need to explicitly import protractor after upgrading to TypeScript 2.0.0, however, my code still displays errors but the tests now execute as expected.

```
[ts] Cannot find name 'browser'
[ts] Cannot find namespace 'protractor'.
```

Is it possible to remove these errors?

Comment: what version of typescript are you using?

Comment: I've defined 4.0.10 in my package.json

Comment: typescript version not protractor

Comment: Sorry, I misread your comment. typescript: 1.8.10

Comment: Since protractor 4.0.5 they are using typescript 2.0. I think you may have to upgrade to 2.0 or downgrade your version of protractor to be compatible with 1.8.

Comment: https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#4.0.5

Comment: Thanks! I did this, and my code now runs (previously it did not), however the errors are still present.

Comment: which one did you do? upgrade typescript or downgrade protractor? If you upgraded you may need to add protractor to the `types` array in your tsconfig. It should be under `compilerOptions`

Comment: I upgraded "typescript": "^2.0.0"  I've also added "types": ["protractor"] to my tsconfig.  I'm still unable to remove the errors when I try to import protractor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that the issue in the end was to do with my /typings folder.  After completely deleting it, **AND** recreating/generating my tsd.json, this solved the issue.

Protractor is not needed in the typings folder, but other dependencies are, and can now reference it using

```
import { browser } from 'protractor'
```

and:

```
import protractor = require('protractor')
```